# Why does to_char() always convert minutes to 07?

Tags: plsql

```
v_dateTime := sysdate;
        
update products
set received_dt = v_dateTime
where id = v_id
and received_dt is null;                   
        
dbms_lob.createtemporary(po_data, true);
po_data := to_clob('{"receivedDateTime": "' || to_char(v_dateTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mm:ss') || '"}');
```

The result of executing this code is a correct datetime value inserted into the table. However, the to_char() function always converts minutes to '07'. The rest of the date and time are correct, but minutes are *always* changed to 07. Why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-DFB23985-2943-4C6A-96DF-DF0F664CED96), the format mask for minutes is **`mi`** - mm is the month.

You need to use:

```
to_char(v_dateTime, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```